# List of all modules

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

From the Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/):

> Any Objective-C framework (or C library) that’s accessible as a module
>   can be imported directly into Swift. This includes all of the
>   Objective-C system frameworks—such as Foundation, UIKit, and
>   SpriteKit—as well as common C libraries supplied with the system.

Where can I find the full list of available modules? I'm particularly interested in the *common C libraries* part.

Comment: Probably in the old Obj-C doc?

Comment: Most likely there is a file or folder with all defined modules, but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same modules that can be imported in Objective-C using the `@import` statement (except the `Swift` module, which is the Swift standard library that is only available in Swift and is always imported in Swift anyway). So what you can do to discover them is:

- Open an Objective-C project, turn support for modules on in build settings
- type `@import ...` and type some letter, delete it, and the autocomplete should show you a list of all the modules you can import.

From what I can tell, besides the standard Cocoa system frameworks (like `Foundation`), the only potentially useful ones are:

- Darwin - most of the C standard library, plus many POSIX things
- ObjectiveC (also imported by `Foundation`) - the Objective-C runtime library (`#import <objc/*>`)
- Dispatch (also imported by `Foundation`) - the dispatch library (`#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>`)